# iPad iOS 7 - How to get rid of the empty place for status bar in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7, statusbar

When I run my iPhone app on an iPad, there's a black bar at the top of the screen where the status bar would be on an iPhone. In iOS 7 the status bar is no longer off-limits to the app's screen real estate (and indeed Apple is pushing us to use this space), yet my iOS-7 iPad still leaves the black bar.

Is there any way to get the content that would show under the status bar on an iPhone to show when the app runs on iPad?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there is a black bar without content on top of the iPhone app area when using ios 7 iPad.

I delete all setStatusBarHidden function and no more strange bar.